# How to publish code in MATLAB with collapsible text?

Tags: python, html, matlab

I recently found that MATLAB's `publish` function is a quite good tool for teaching, since it provides a nice view of the code an its outputs. The only (very) bad point is that there is no interactivity, as in the live code execution provided by the python notebook for instance. If I do not want to show all the solutions in the same time to my students, the only solution is to play with the scrolling of the page, and I am not yet an expert.

Thus, I am looking for a way to dynamically hide and show some parts using the `publish` function, like MATLAB's html pages on the MathWork website (see [the documentation](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/publish.html?searchHighlight=publish#btbso1m), where there are some examples of collapsible parts).

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but there is a MATLAB notebook for the new Jupyter project, which is the successor to IPython (IPython is now the Python plugin for Jupyter).

Comment: The answer is no you cant nowadays. The ipython notebook (jupyter nowadays) its very amazing, and as @TheBlackCat suggest nowadays accepts Matlab also. That is your solution